# Using Visual Basic to construct a tailored leaflet based on answers stored in Excel?

Tags: vbscript, vb6

I would like to create a relatively simple program that looks at a set of responses to a questionnaire and then from this constructs a tailored leaflet from A5 panels based on those responses.
I have the database of responses stored already.

So basically I have a collection of A5 pages, i need the program to look at an individuals data for example "Does this person like cheese?" IF Yes then include A5 panel about cheese.
Constructing a printable leaflet.

Is this something that can be created in Visual Basic? Or would an alternative language be better for this process?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Word and set-up a mail merge?

At least using Word you can manipulate the document as you want it, change the info in the spread sheet and then republish as and when you require.

See here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx

So, to answer your question, Visual Basic of any sort would be the least appropriate , whereas a mail merge or desktop publishing package would give you your best results.